# Angular build - Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'console'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, deployment, module

I have a problem with my Angular project build, and ultimately deployment to heroku. I'm using an old(ish) npm package called binary parser, which causes the following error on when I build / deploy to heroku: 
`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'console' in '/tmp/build_e75b87f248f44978f9537d83b3172254/node_modules/binary-parser/dist'`

The binary-parser.js has a line `require("console");` which is used in exactly one place, so local builds succeed and the application works perfectly, if only I remove console from that line altogether. But as, heroku installs node modules when deploying, this only helps when I manually build the prod version.

I have installed typings for binary-parser and for TS, and also included "types": ["node"] in both tsconfig.json and tsconfig.app.json compilerOptions.

As angular these days doesn't really allow for webpack configuration, I've tried adding `global.console = global.console || require('console-browserify');`
(or)
`global.console = global.console || require('console');`
to my polyfills, to no avail.

Any ideas on how to solve this? Do I need to configure a custom webpack to circumvent this? I'll gladly post additional information if necessary!

Answer (score 11):

Here's a possible cause, may or may not be what you or others reading this question are experiencing...

My IDE's auto importing added `import * as console from "console";` when I typed `console.log`.

Solution was of course to remove that import statement.

Comment: In my case it was WebStorm

Answer (score 1):

After trying for multiple hours to come up with the right configuration, the only solution I could come up with was forking the repo in question and changing tsconfig target from es5 to es6, which got rid of the console import altogether upon compilation.